# What happens with an asymmetric autoencoder?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, linear-model, autoencoders

Suppose I have an antoencoder where the encoder is a nonlinear function eg Neural Net, and the decoder is a linear mapping. Would this type of autoencoder be able to achieve a lower training loss than if the autoencoder was simply linear on both sides? Is there any strange behaviour that this kind of model would produce?